# AngularJS not printing value of $event

Tags: angularjs

I am using below example and it's not printing the value defined in `$event`

Below is my app.js

```
var myModule = angular.module("myModule",[])
myModule.controller("myController",function($scope){

    $scope.someName = "test";

})
```

Below is my html

```
<html ng-app="myModule">

<head></head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="myController">

  This is Angular JS {{ someName }}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no issues with your code. Make sure you have refered **`angularjs`** reference as below

**DEMO**

```js
var myModule = angular.module("myModule",[])
myModule.controller("myController",function($scope){
   $scope.someName = "test";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myModule">
<head></head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="myController">
  This is Angular JS {{ someName }}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have done and strangely it throws ncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

Comment: Which means you have not refered angularjs script

Comment: Please get those `<script>` and `ng-app` into their place. Should be in `head` and `body` respectively.

Comment: @RaphaMex not necessarily

Comment: It's my mistake..after adding <script> to angularJS and also my app.js it started working